# How do I put unordered list items into an array

Tags: javascript

My code is...

How do I get the text in each list item into an array using native javascript?

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementById('list').childNodes.TextNode;
for(var i=0;i < list.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = list[i];
    alert(arrValue);
}
</script>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want the text-nodes between each `<li>` it's not a good idea to use `childNodes`. What's wrong with `getElementsByTagName('li')`?

```
var listItems = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('li'),

    myArray = map(listItems, getText);

function map(arrayLike, fn) {
    var ret = [], i = -1, len = arrayLike.length;
    while (++i < len) ret[i] = fn(arrayLike[i]);
    return ret;
}

function getText(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) return node.data;
    var txt = '';
    if (node = node.firstChild) do {
        txt += getText(node);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
    return txt;
}
```

Comment: best so far, though nested lists would be a problem if any existed, as `getElementsByTagName` is of course hierarchical. Why not just `map(listItems, getText)`, though?

Comment: @bibince, changed to `map(listItems, getText)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list').childNodes;
var theArray = [];
for(var i=0;i < list.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = list[i].innerHTML;
    alert(arrValue);
    theArray.push(arrValue);
}
```

Comment: `childNodes` contains whitespace Text nodes, for which `innerHTML` is not defined. `innerHTML` will return escaped characters for some text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var LIs = document.getElementById('list').childNodes;
var list = [];
for( var i = 0; i < LIs.length; ++i )
{
    var LI = LIs[i];
    list.push(LI.innerText || LI.textContent);
}
```

And as always, the simpler way using jQuery:

```
var list = $('#list li').map(function(){ return $(this).text(); });
```

Comment: `childNodes` contains whitespace Text nodes that are unwanted in the list (and for which `innerText` is not defined). `||` test fails for empty-string `innerText`, leaving IE to put `undefined` in array.

Comment: With jQuery it's *even* simpler: `var list = $('#list li').map(function(){return $.text([this])});`

Answer (score 1):

Just about any [Javascript library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) ([Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), ...) will make this easier, but if you want to do it yourself:

You're close, your Javascript should look something like this:

```
window.onload = onPageLoad; // Or any of several other similar mechanisms
                            // (you could just run it at the bottom of the page)
function onPageLoad() {
    var node, list, arrValue;

    list = [];
    for (node = document.getElementById('list').firstChild;
        node;
        node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == 'LI') {
            list.push(node.innerHTML);
        }
    }

    // `list` now contains the HTML of each LI element under the `ul#list` element
}
```

Explanation:

- Before using `document.getElementById`, you need to be sure that the DOM is ready for you to do that. It's definitely ready at `onload` time, and there are various mechanisms for triggering your code a bit earlier than that if you like (including putting the script right at the end).
- The loop starts by getting the `ul#list` element's first child, then continues as long as there are further siblings.
- In the loop, we check that each node is an Element (`nodeType == 1`) and that its tag name is "LI".
- If it is, we retrieve its HTML and push it on the array.

I've used `innerHTML` to retrieve the content of the LIs because it's widely supported. Alternately, you could use `innerText` on IE (and some others) and `textContent` on Firefox, but beware that they don't do *quite* the same thing (`textContent` on Firefox will include the contents of `script` tags, for instance, which probably isn't what you want).

Comment: @J-P: That's certainly an option; it's a loop either way, using `getElementsByTagName` requires a second function call and creation of a NodeList, which seems unnecesary if you're going to loop anyway. (Is that your downvote? If so, seems a bit harsh just for going a different way...)

Answer (score 0):

var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');

```
var theArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = list[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(arrValue);
    theArray.push(arrValue);
}
```

Comment: nickf's answer basically but using getElementsByTagName instead of using childnodes